# How can I create a camera from current view in maya with Python?

Tags: python, camera, maya

I am new to python, and would like to know how I can create a camera from current view in maya with a simple python script.

Comment: You'll get better answers (and less risk of people downvoting the question) if you provide some idea of what you've tried and what you think you should try.  The [Question guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) give some advice on what kinds of info to include

Answer (score 3):

The native Maya code is here(MEL): maya20xx/scripts/others/MTprocs.mel

```
global proc MTcreateCameraFromView(){
        string $curPanel = `getPanel -wf`;
        if(`getPanel -typeOf $curPanel` == "modelPanel") {
            string $camera = `modelPanel -q -cam $curPanel`;
            string $newCameras[] = `duplicate $camera`;
            string $newCamera = $newCameras[0];
            showHidden $newCamera;
            lookThroughModelPanel $newCamera $curPanel;
        }
}
```

Basically it's just getting the current camera and duplicating it.
You can even call this function using

```
import maya.mel
maya.mel.eval("melcommand")
```